# multiple custom fields in joomla3.1

Tags: xml, field, joomla3.1

how do I create multiple custom fields in joomla 3.1? What I mean how to make to return multiple input fields from model/fields/myfields.php->getInput();

reading the following tutorial  http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type I have an example just for one item.

Answer (score 0):

You create your custom field(s) and on the form you call the custom filed(s) you wish to use. Ex:

models/fields/my_custom_feld_one.php // file that defines your custom field one

models/fields/my_custom_feld_two.php // file that defines your custom field two

In your form, in models/forms/your_form.xml

```
<field name="my_custom_feld_one"
  type="text"
  class="inputbox"
  label="Your label"
  description="Your description"/>

<field name="my_custom_feld_two"
  type="text"
  class="inputbox"
  label="Your label"
  description="Your description"/>
```

Now, when the form is rendered, Joomla will take care of rendering your custom fields.